# Value of ingestion_time() not going beyond mv-expand operator

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

My requirement is the following logic

```
  MyTable
        | where ingestion_time() >= ago(1d)
        | mv-expand todynamic(SomeColumnContainingArrayStoredAsString)
        | project category='somecategory', body = pack_all() 
        | extend partitiontime=ingestion_time() 
        | take 10
```

So ideally this should produce 3 column resultset as following:-

1. category (`string`)
2. body (`dynamic`)
3. partitiontime (`datetime`)

I very much need the value of `ingestion_time()` to go to the calculated column `partitiontime`. But it's always blank in the output. Based on my observation , it seems that the value of `ingestion_time()` is getting lost because of `mv-expand`. But I can't do away with `mv-expand`. I also need partitiontime as a separate column , so I don't want it to go into `body`. That's why I am trying to issue the `extend` operator for `partitiontime` as the last thing. But that's not working , so it's a tricky situation. I am not sure how else can I make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ingestiontimefunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer): *This function must be used in context of a table for which the IngestionTime policy is enabled. Otherwise, this function produces null values.*

meaning, you'll need to rewrite your query as follows:

```
MyTable
| extend partitiontime = ingestion_time() 
| where partitiontime() >= ago(1d)
| mv-expand todynamic(SomeColumnContainingArrayStoredAsString)
| project category='somecategory',
          body = bag_remove_keys(pack_all(), dynamic(["partitiontime"]),
          partitiontime
| take 10
```